# Trying to write a PHP function for mysql, SELECT SUM()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a PHP function which gets the sum of values in 1 column of a table. MY SQL statement works just fine. However, when I write my function and attempt to echo the variable into my HTML code, it returns '0'.

Here is my function:

```
function get_asset_value($org_ID) {
global $db;
$query = "SELECT SUM(asset_value) FROM assets
          WHERE org_ID = '$org_ID'";
$asset_sum = $db->query($query);
$asset_sum = $asset_sum->fetch();
return $asset_sum;
```

In my HTML, I have the following:

```
<?php echo $asset_sum; ?>
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with the "fetch" portion of my function. I really don't know what fetch does but I tried copying/modifying this piece of code from a working function (which doesn't return the sum, but it is a select statement).

Thank you!

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injection , maybe you could use prepared statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(asset_value) AS the_sum FROM assets WHERE ord_ID = '$ord_ID';
```

...

```
return $asset_sum['the_sum'];
```

The issue is, you are returning an entire record, rather than just the field you want.

Also, judging by the way you are inserting that ID in your query, I suspect you are open to SQL injection.  You should really [learn to do prepared queries with PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Comment: Thanks, Brad. That totally worked. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to

```
SELECT SUM(asset_value) AS the_sum FROM assets WHERE ord_ID = '$ord_ID';
...
return $asset_sum['the_sum']
```

by Brad,

you better do

```
$safer = mysql_real_escape_string($org_ID);
```

then do,

```
SELECT SUM(asset_value) AS the_sum FROM assets WHERE ord_ID = '$safer';
...
return $asset_sum['the_sum']
```